# How to call a function several times in the same line using an operator

Tags: c++, return, operator-overloading, operators

This function adds a `TElement` to a `vector<TElement>`:

```
friend void operator<<(ToDo& todu, const ElementT& D) {
    todu.add(D);
    return;
}
```

I want to call it like this:

```
todo << elem1 << elem2 << elem3 << elem4...
```

Comment: You want to return a `ToDo&` from the function. `todo << elem1` is equivalent to `operator<<(todo, elem1)`, `todo << elem1 << elem2` is equivalent to `operator<<(operator<<(todo, elem1), elem2)`, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to chain operations like that, then you can simply return the `ToDo` parameter by reference, like this:

```
friend ToDo& operator<<(ToDo& todu, const ElementT& D) 
{
    todu.add(D);
    return todu;
}
```

and now you should be able to use `operator<<` like this:

```
todo << elem1 << elem2 << elem3 << elem4;
```